# What is the purpose of having an empty pair base class?

Tags: c++, libstdc++

[libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_pair.h#L189)'s implementation of pair has the following oddity

```
template<typename, typename> class __pair_base
  {
    template<typename T, typename U> friend struct pair;
    __pair_base() = default;
    ~__pair_base() = default;
    __pair_base(const __pair_base&) = default;
    __pair_base& operator=(const __pair_base&) = delete;
  };

template<typename T, typename U>
  struct pair
  : private __pair_base<T, U>
{ /* never uses __pair_base */ };
```

`__pair_base` is never used, neither can it, considering it's empty. This is particularly confusing since `std::pair` is [required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/pairs#pair-4) to be conditionally structural

> `pair<T, U>` is a structural type if `T` and `U` are both structural types.

And having private bases makes it non-structural.

Comment: Here can find the authors comments: https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2018-10/msg00851.html They tried to solve some ambiguity issues while being ABI-compatible. But this fix makes it non-conformant to the standard as you observed correctly. Practically it seems to change nearly nothing, or?

Comment: Note that the structural-type requirement is quite new (it was added in the last C++20 meeting, in February); the necessary changes may just not have happened yet.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

tl;dr This is the result of a really long series of hacks to implement the insane overload/explicit rules of `std::pair` and maintain ABI compatibility. It is a bug in C++20.

---

### Disclaimer

This is more of a "fun" ride along with the standard library authors down memory lane then some insightful language level revelation. It shows how extremely complicated C++ has became that implementing a *pair*, of all things, is a herculean task.

I tried my best recreating the history, but I'm not one of the authors.

### Pair Primer

`std::pair` is much more than simply

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct pair
{
    T first;
    U second;
};
```

There are 8 different constructors listed on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), and for an implementer, it's even more: every conditionally explicit constructor is actually *two* constructors, one for implicit, another for explicit.

Not all of these constructors participate in overload resolution, if they did, there would be ambiguity everywhere. Instead, there are many many rules governing when each does, and  *every* combination of the aforementioned cases have to be written and disabled manually by SFINAE.

This culminated to 5 bug reports throughout the years on the *constructors alone*. Now about to become 6 ;)

### Prologue

The [first bug](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/7b3318c41e6165140e59e026988d1f6e27d01a2a) is about short-circuiting the checks of convertibility of the pair parameters if the types are the same.

```
template<typename T> struct B;
template<typename T> struct A
{
    A(A&&) = default;
    A(const B<T> &);
};

template<typename T> struct B
{
    pair<A<T>, int> a;
    B(B&&) = default;
};
```

Apparently, if they checked convertibility too early, the move constructor gets deleted due to the circular dependency and how `B` is still incomplete within `A`.

### `nonesuch`

This however [changed the SFINAE properties](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/f524d5b34aaac95cb4b2ce7126002cd4fa9d5bae) of `pair`. In response, another fix was implemented. This implementation enabled previously invalid assignment operators, and so the assignment operators were turned off manually by changing their signatures

```
struct nonesuch
{
    nonesuch() = delete;
    ~nonesuch() = delete;
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
    void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};

// ...
pair& operator=(
    conditional_t<conjunction_v<is_copy_assignable<T>,
                                is_copy_assignable<U>>,
                  const pair&, const nonesuch&>::type)
```

Where `nonesuch` is a dummy type that essentially makes this overload uncallable. Or is it?

### `no_braces_nonesuch`

Unfortunately, even though you couldn't ever create a `nonesuch`

```
pair<int, int> p = {};  // succeeds
p = {};  // fails
```

you could still [initialize it with braces](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/c1e2889a320a2e45eb60b6bb7c1d3d8fc0068582). Since `delete` doesn't resolve overload resolution, this is a hard failure.

The fix was to create `no_braces_nonesuch`

```
struct no_braces_nonesuch : nonesuch
{
    explicit no_braces_nonesuch(const no_braces_nonesuch&) = delete;
};
```

The `explicit` turns off participation in overload resolution. Finally, the assignment is uncallable. Or is it...?

### `__pair_base` v1

There is, unfortunately, [another way to initialize](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/e182158261869320bc6fb1e972fd5a142359965e) an unknown type

```
struct anything
{
    template<typename T>
    operator T() { return {}; }
};

anything a;
pair<int, int> p;
p = a;
```

The authors realized they could solve this "easily" by leveraging the default generated special member functions: they could be not declared at all if you have a base that is non-assignable

```
class __pair_base
  {
    template<typename T, typename U> friend struct pair;
    __pair_base() = default;
    ~__pair_base() = default;
    __pair_base(const __pair_base&) = default;
    __pair_base& operator=(const __pair_base&) = delete;
  };
```

All unit tests passed, and things are looking bright. Unbeknownst, the shadow of an evil bug looms ominously on the horizon.

### `__pair_base` v2

ABI broke.

How is that even remotely possible? [Empty bases are optimized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) out aren't they? Well, no.

```
pair<pair<int, int>, int> p;
```

Unfortunately, empty base optimization only applies if the base class subobjects are non-overlapping with other subobjects of the same type. In this case, the `__pair_base` of the inner pair overlaps with the one of the outer pair.

The fix was "simple", we templatize `__pair_base` to ensure they are different types.

### Structural Types

C++20 came, and it requires that pair be [structural types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). This requires that there is no private bases.

```
template<pair<int, int>>
struct S;  // fails
```

So ends our journey. This reminds me of [Chandler Carruth's quick survey at cppcon](https://youtu.be/LJh5QCV4wDg?t=2455): "who can build a C++ compiler in a year if they needed to?" Only current compiler writers think they could, given how complicated C++ is. Apparently, I don't even know how to implement `std::pair`.

Comment: +1 for the context and demonstration. If my upcoming attempt at a simple application in Mbed OS doesn't drive me entirely mad, I might ask "Is C++ a mystery cult?" next April.

Comment: Re last sentence. Then again, `std::pair` is (to be) implemented in C++ and not part of the compiler itself