# What is the performance problem with std::pair assignment operator?

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-optimization

I have watched the talk [Danila Kutenin — C++ STL best and worst performance features](https://youtu.be/ifQMVC8fAdE?t=962) (including one other version of the same talk), I have read the [blog](https://danlark.org/2020/04/13/why-is-stdpair-broken/), but I still do not understand what is preventing optimization of std::pair assignment operator.

[godbolt link of the comparison with custom pair](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jqdva3), code inlined here:

```
struct MyPair {
    int a;
    int b;
};

// slower
void CopyPair(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& a,
              std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& b) {
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
}

// faster
void SmartCopyPair(const std::vector<MyPair>& a,
                   std::vector<MyPair>& b) {
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
}
```

Comment: Not a dupe but somewhat related: [What is the purpose of having an empty `pair` base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931324/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-an-empty-pair-base-class)

Comment: Could you summarize what you expect /  what you are demonstrating? I'm not inclined to follow external links to get the gist of a SO question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue of C++ but rather of the STL implementation you use.

If you write following checks

```
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<MyPair>,"MyPair is not trivially copyable");
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::pair<int,int>>,"std pair is not trivially copyable");
```

You'll notice that only the second line fails to compile. This isn't the case for all STL implementations but only the one you compile on and possibly some other.

When `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>` is true then `std::copy` of vector of `T` is probably implementation level optimized to `memcpy` on the whole range instead of calling copy per element.

Comment: The Standard's specification of `std::pair` doesn't allow it to ever be trivially copyable, unless I've missed something.

Comment: @aschepler according to cpp reference it seems that `std::pair` is supposed to be trivially copy constructible but no concrete info about copy assignment. It looks contracting to me and I don't see any reason why forcefully disable trivial copy assignment if the type allows it. From my understanding the implementation simply didn't change much since C++98 and changing it is an ABI break.

Comment: You're saying it's an implementation choice based on ABI concerns (in which stdlib?). Is there any standard library implementation that manages to make copy assignment trivial?

Comment: @JeffGarrett MSCV does. Although, it could that they just don't follow standart on this point. They occasionally have deviations.

Comment: Hmm, apparently C++20 makes this *way* easier to accomplish...